# Quanitiy Shipped in odoo Invoice report

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I'm trying to get the value qty of products shipped to display as an additional column in the invoice report. Not sure if its as simple as finding out what variable it is or what. Is there any easy way to reference what variables are available for the current views?

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="hidden">Source Document</th>
        <th class="text-right">Ordered</th>
        <th class="text-right">Shipped</th>
        <th class="text-right">Backorder</th>
        <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
        <th t-if="display_discount" class="text-right">Disc.(%)</th>
        <th class="text-right">Extended Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="invoice_tbody">
    <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
        <td><span t-field="l.name"/></td>
        <td class="hidden"><span t-field="l.origin"/></td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
            <span t-field="l.uom_id" groups="product.group_uom"/>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <span t-field="o.delivery_count"/>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">

        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
        </td>
        <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right">
            <span t-field="l.discount"/>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <span t-field="l.price_subtotal" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you mean with "products shipped" but you can get the quantity of the invoice lines to your report like this:

```xml
<t t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
    <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
</t>
```

Same for the stock picking lines quantity:

```xml
<t t-foreach="o.move_lines" t-as="l">
    <span t-field="l.product_uom_qty"/>
</t>
```

One easy way to get the variable names is to activate the develop mode and placing the cursor over a field label.

You can also go to Settings->Database Structure->Models then just pick your needed model to see the variable names (field names).

Comment: Hi, this seems like a great help. When you mean debug mode, do you mean the odoo developer mode or by placing the debug snippet in the qweb template?

By quantity shipped, I guess I mean quantity delivered. The problem is this value seems to be in a different report, how can I reference it yet relate to the correct item? I am currently using odoo10.

Comment: I also added a code example of what I'm working on in the invoice report.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have figured out a good portion of the problem based on your suggestions. The only problem now is I need for example: "client_order_ref" from sale.order and I need to display it in an account.invoice report.

Simply referencing o.client_order_ref directly doesn't work I'm assuming because the corresponding sales order is not referenced.

Comment: I mean the develop mode. You are right, it's not possible to call a field from a different model. Therefore you need to create a new model combining account invoice and sale order and that's some work to to: http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/postgres-views.html
But i still don't get why you just not use the quantity of your invoice lines, cause quantity shipped is the same as quantity you sell?